# Is a Python list guaranteed to have its elements stay in the order they are inserted in?

Tags: python

If I have the following Python code

```
>>> x = []
>>> x = x + [1]
>>> x = x + [2]
>>> x = x + [3]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
```

Will `x` be guaranteed to always be `[1,2,3]`, or are other orderings of the interim elements possible?

Comment: A list, by definition, is an ordered sequence of items, accessible by their indices.

Comment: I don't understand how this question is not reasonable. Not all languages store their lists type objects in insert-order (Java, Lua, etc) and not all collections in Python are maintained in insert-order (dicts). Seems perfectly reasonable to ask to me.

Answer (score 636, accepted):

Yes, the order of elements in a python list is persistent.

Comment: This is the right answer so I don't want to add another.  He could also use list.append to really put his mind at ease.  http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: what if I return a local list from a function and use that in the calling function. That is `def fn_1(): lst = [] lst.append(1) lst.append(2) return lst` and `def fn_2(): print(fn_1())` Will the order be same ALWAYS irrespective of how many times or where ever I use fn_1() ?

Comment: Yes, the order of elements in a python list is persistent. ;)

Answer (score 113):

In short, yes, the order is preserved. In long:

In general the following definitions will always apply to objects like lists:

A **list** is a collection of elements that can contain duplicate elements and has a defined order that generally does not change unless explicitly made to do so. **stacks** and **queues** are both types of lists that provide specific (often limited) behavior for adding and removing elements (stacks being LIFO, queues being FIFO). Lists are practical representations of, well, lists of things. A string can be thought of as a list of characters, as the order is important (`"abc" != "bca"`) and duplicates in the content of the string are certainly permitted (`"aaa"` can exist and `!= "a"`).

A **set** is a collection of elements that cannot contain duplicates and has a non-definite order that may or may not change over time. Sets do not represent lists of things so much as they describe the *extent* of a certain selection of things. The internal structure of set, how its elements are stored relative to each other, is usually not meant to convey useful information. In some implementations, sets are always internally sorted; in others the ordering is simply undefined (usually depending on a hash function).

**Collection** is a generic term referring to any object used to store a (usually variable) number of other objects. Both lists and sets are a type of collection. Tuples and Arrays are normally not considered to be collections. Some languages consider **maps** (containers that describe associations between different objects) to be a type of collection as well.

This naming scheme holds true for all programming languages that I know of, including Python, C++, Java, C#, and Lisp (in which lists not keeping their order would be particularly catastrophic). If anyone knows of any where this is not the case, please just say so and I'll edit my answer. Note that specific implementations may use other names for these objects, such as **vector** in C++ and **flex** in ALGOL 68 (both lists; flex is technically just a re-sizable array).

If there is any confusion left in your case due to the specifics of how the `+` sign works here, just know that order is *important* for lists and unless there is very good reason to believe otherwise you can pretty much always safely assume that list operations preserve order. In this case, the `+` sign behaves much like it does for strings (which are really just lists of characters anyway): it takes the content of a list and places it behind the content of another.

If we have

```
list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Then

```
list1 + list2
```

Is the same as

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] + [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Which evaluates to

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Much like

```
"abdcde" + "fghijk"
```

Produces

```
"abdcdefghijk"
```

Comment: I read somewhere that since the specification of a JSON array does not specify that arrays maintain order array operations are not guaranteed to maintain order. I can't find the source for that, though.
And the underlying structure of an Array is still a special case of an object with numbered indexes, so it's not a contradiction to your statement, just an interesting tidbit, I thought.

Comment: I do not agree with the explication of set. Sets are definitely not "geared more towards mathematical and theoretical purposes than real-life ones". Instead, sets are very useful any time one needs a collection containing items that cannot be repeated, and offer tools such as difference and intersection that are useful in modeling real life use cases.

Comment: @Pintun looking back several years after writing this post I agree with you. I'll edit once I figure out a better way to express what I was aiming at.

Answer (score 10):

You are confusing 'sets' and 'lists'.  A set does not guarantee order, but lists do.

Sets are declared using curly brackets: `{}`. In contrast, lists are declared using square brackets: `[]`.

```
mySet = {a, b, c, c}
```

Does not guarantee order, but list does:

```
myList = [a, b, c]
```

Comment: Note that a set *also* guarantees non-duplication. A list may have duplicate elements, a set may not.

Comment: Dictionaries also use curly brackets.

Comment: A dictionary's lookup keys are a 'set', there can not be duplicates.  So it does make a lot of sense for both sets and dictionaries to use curly braces.

Comment: Or... a set is a dictionary without a payload / data-structure behind the keys. Again, they are very similar

Answer (score 5):

I suppose one thing that may be concerning you is whether or not the entries could change, so that the 2 becomes a different number, for instance. You can put your mind at ease here, because in Python, integers are *immutable*, meaning they cannot change after they are created.

Not everything in Python is immutable, though. For example, lists are mutable---they can change after being created.  So for example, if you had a list of lists

```
>>> a = [[1], [2], [3]]
>>> a[0].append(7)
>>> a
[[1, 7], [2], [3]]
```

Here, I changed the first entry of `a` (I added `7` to it). One could imagine shuffling things around, and getting unexpected things here if you are not careful (and indeed, this does happen to everyone when they start programming in Python in some way or another; just search this site for "modifying a list while looping through it" to see dozens of examples).

It's also worth pointing out that `x = x + [a]` and `x.append(a)` are not the same thing. The second one mutates `x`, and the first one creates a new list and assigns it to `x`. To see the difference, try setting `y = x` before adding anything to `x` and trying each one, and look at the difference the two make to `y`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the list will remain as [1,2,3] unless you perform some other operation on it.

Answer (score 0):

aList=[1,2,3]

i=0

```
for item in aList:  

    if i<2:  

            aList.remove(item)  

    i+=1
```

aList

[2]

The moral is when modifying a list in a loop driven by the list, takes two steps:

```
aList=[1,2,3]
i=0
for item in aList:
    if i<2:
        aList[i]="del"
    i+=1

aList

['del', 'del', 3]
for i in range(2):
    del aList[0]

aList
[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes lists and tuples are always ordered while dictionaries are not

Comment: Except in Python 3 :D

Answer (score 0):

In short ‘yes’ a list in Python always maintains the insert order, and by default it is interpreted as Deque which is LIFO (using pop and append) on the contrary you can reverse list to be functional as a queue.

Comment: For those unfamiliar; `Deque`=[double-ended_queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue)