# Django: Is there an attribute to Client() get/post response that indicates final URL

Tags: python, django, redirect

I've found a few questions relating to the testing of URL redirects, to see if URL redirects land at the desired target URL. I would like to know, though, if there is an attribute that indicates what the final target URL landed upon is.

```
c = Client()
r = c.get('/sr/portfolios/', follow=True)
r.final_url # something like this?
```

It seems redirect_chain only tells you URLs you were redirected through, but not those than you ultimately landed on.

```
r.redirect_chain
# [('http://testserver/sr/?next=/sr/portfolios/', 302)]
```

Related (but not identical) topic I found: [Django : Testing if the page has redirected to the desired url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951356/django-testing-if-the-page-has-redirected-to-the-desired-url)

Comment: Isn't it simply ``r.url``?

Comment: r.url returns: AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'url'

Comment: My bad, sorry. But you can get the final path, if that's enough for you, in ``r.request['PATH_INFO']``. I'd also expect that the last element in redirect_chain is the final url, but I haven't checked.

Comment: I thought the last item in `redirect_chain` was what you actually landed on..?

Comment: Thanks @axelcdv; `r.request['PATH_INFO']` works perfectly - awesome. Didn't realize r.request returned that dict. As an aside, `redirect_chain` does not return final location: `>>> r.request['PATH_INFO']` returns `'/sr/'` and `>>> r.redirect_chain` returns `[('http://testserver/sr/?next=/sr/portfolios/', 302)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to highlight the solution a bit, you can get the final url with `r.request['PATH_INFO']`. `r.wsgi_request.META['PATH_INFO']` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are other ways of doing this, but would a simple `in` check suffice?

```
def test_final_url(self):

    final_url = reverse('your_url_name')

    found = False
    for item in r.redirect_chain:
        if final_url in item[0]:
            found = True
            break

    self.assertTrue(found)
```

Since Python lists don't have a guaranteed order, I'm not sure it's 100% safe to look at `r.redirect_chain[-1][0]` but it might be the fastest solution.

Comment: A lists order is guaranteed in Python, you're thinking of dict?

Comment: I stand humbly corrected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694034/is-a-python-list-guaranteed-to-have-its-elements-stay-in-the-order-they-are-inse