# Templates with argument in string formatting

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, formatting

I'm looking for a package or any other approach (other than manual replacement) for the templates within string formatting.

**I want to achieve something like this** (this is just an example so you could get the idea, not the actual working code):

```
text = "I {what:like,love} {item:pizza,space,science}".format(what=2,item=3)
print(text)
```

**So the output would be**:

`I love science`

How can I achieve this? I have been searching but cannot find anything appropriate. Probably used wrong naming terms.

---

If there isnt any ready to use package around I would love to read some tips on the starting point to code this myself.

Comment: Are you using python > 3.6 or python < 3.6?

Comment: I'm using the latest version available, so > 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one have provided an appropriate answer that answers my question directly, I decided to work on this myself.

I had to use double brackets, because single ones are reserved for the string formatting.

I ended up with the following class:

```
class ArgTempl:
    def __init__(self, _str):
        self._str = _str

    def format(self, **args):
        for k in re.finditer(r"{{(\w+):([\w,]+?)}}", self._str,
                             flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE):
            key, replacements = k.groups()

            if not key in args:
                continue

            self._str = self._str.replace(k.group(0), replacements.split(',')[args[key]])

        return self._str
```

This is a primitive, 5 minute written code, therefore lack of checks and so on. It works as expected and can be improved easly.

Tested on Python 2.7 & 3.6~

Usage:

```
test = "I {{what:like,love}} {{item:pizza,space,science}}"
print(ArgTempl(test).format(what=1, item=2))
> I love science
```

Thanks for all of the replies.

Answer (score 1):

My be use a list or a tuple for `what` and `item` as both data types preserve insertion order.

```
what = ['like', 'love']
item = ['pizza', 'space', 'science']

text = "I {what} {item}".format(what=what[1],item=item[2])
print(text)    # I like science
```

or even this is possible.

```
text = "I {what[1]} {item[2]}".format(what=what, item=item)
print(text)  # I like science
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You should change `what[2]` and `item[3]` to `what[1]` and `item[2]` otherwise you'll get an `IndexError`

Answer (score 1):

I think using list is sufficient since [python lists are persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694034/is-a-python-list-guaranteed-to-have-its-elements-stay-in-the-order-they-are-inse)

```
what = ["like","love"]
items = ["pizza","space","science"]
text = "I {} {}".format(what[1],items[2])
print(text)
```

output:
    I love science

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a dictionary?

```
options = {'what': ('like', 'love'), 'item': ('pizza', 'space', 'science')}
print("I " + options['what'][1] + ' ' + options['item'][2])
```

This returns: "I love science"

Or if you wanted a method to rid yourself of having to reformat to accommodate/remove spaces, then incorporate this into your dictionary structure, like so:

```
options = {'what': (' like', ' love'), 'item': (' pizza', ' space', ' science'), 'fullstop': '.'}
print("I" + options['what'][0] + options['item'][0] + options['fullstop'])
```

And this returns: "I like pizza."