# Order a django queryset with specific objects first

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a list of users displaying in templates like the following.

```
{% for u in users_list %}

    {{u.name}}

{% endif %}
```

Is there a way to rank two or more users at the top If I want to?

For instance with one user, when the current user visits that list, I can rank him in the top *without a specific ordering* by excluding me before sending the variable to template.

```
1) me
2) user2
3) user3
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to order specific objects by id at the top of a queryset, you can order on a [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) - for example, to put the current user at the top, and order other users by name:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

users = User.objects.order_by(
    Case(When(id=request.user.id, then=0), default=1),
    'last_name',
    'first_name'
)
```

To put multiple objects at the top, just adjust the `When` condition:

```
ids_at_top = [1, 2]
users = User.objects.order_by(
    Case(When(id__in=ids_at_top, then=0), default=1))
```

I would also consider though whether you can achieve what you want via simpler means - for example you could get the current user, exclude them from the main queryset, and then display separately in the template, like this

```
# in the view
current_user = request.user
users = User.objects.exclude(id=current_user.id)

# in the template
{{ current_user.name }}
{% for u in users %}
  {{ u.name }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: the fact of ranking one user was just an example, this is my question: How can I rank two or more users at the top If I want to?

Comment: Awesome, pure django ORM!

Answer (score 1):

In your view create a list of users that you want to display. In order to display the current user you can use `request.user` to get the current user and append them to the list followed by the rest of the users. In your template you would do

```
<ol type="1">
{% for u in users_list %}

    <li>{{u.name}}<li>

{% endif %}
</ol>
```

should out what you are looking for

#### Update example

```
user_list = list(Users.objects.filter(name="Test")) #Or how ever you want to get the users.
user_list.insert(0,request.user)
```

if you wanted to get another individual you would just get the user using

```
another_person = User.objects.get(id=some_id)
user_list.insert(0,another_person)
```

Comment: the fact of ranking one user was just an example, this is my question: How can I rank two or more users at the top If I want to?

Comment: This would happen in the same way. In your view you create user_list and then you can add who ever you want to the list and user will be displayed in that order when you iterate through in the template.

Comment: Are you sure the ordering within a list will be same in templates?

Comment: Yes the order should be preserved. Here is a post about the topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694034/is-a-python-list-guaranteed-to-have-its-elements-stay-in-the-order-they-are-inse

Comment: Also I didn't mention that in the insert method used above you can change the insert position by changing the 0 to the index you want to insert at

Answer (score 0):

Usign the queryset you can order your `users_list` based on the fields in the User. For this purpose you have the `sort` method in the queryset. In your case seems to me you need to add a field so you can sort by that field. For example you add a rank field default 0 and than add a value for the hightest rank.

The full example is defined here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

In your `CustomUserMdel` just add a field `rank = models.IntegerField(default=0)`

Then in your view you need to sort by rank:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

# in your view...
user_list = User.objects.all().sort_by('rank')
```