# Django query to keep perticular item at first and then apply order_by to rest of the items

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset, django-orm

Let say we have an Article model.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id = int
    name = char
```

i want to get all the articles but the article with name = "stackoverflow" should be the first item in queryset and apply order_by to rest of the items. eg .order_by("name").

what i've achieved so far is

```
queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by("name")
stackoverflow = queryset.get(name="stackoverflow")
query = queryset.exclude(name="stackoverflow")
articles = []
articles.extend(stackoverflow)
articles.extend(query)
```

But this hits the database atleast 4 times.
Can we do this in a better way?

Comment: How is that 5 times? From what I understand only two queries should be made with this snippet. Check [When QuerySets are evaluated - Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

Comment: its taking 4 hits. `stackoverflow = queryset.get(name="stackoverflow")` here 1
`query = queryset.exclude(name="stackoverflow")` here 1
`articles.extend(stackoverflow)` here 1
`articles.extend(query)` here 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Case, When

articles = Article.objects.order_by(
    Case(When(name="stackoverflow", then=0), default=1)
)
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/

[Order a django queryset with specific objects first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047107/order-a-django-queryset-with-specific-objects-first)