# Django: sorting querysets to have a specific order of objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I've a model with two fields, say `deprecated` and `new`. When I'm listing the objects, I'd like the ones with `new=True` at the beginning, followed by the objects where `deprecated is not None` and then the rest.
I've seen a bunch of answers about ordering by multiple fields but that doesn't seem to work for me. This is how I'm doing the ordering now:

```
class Meta:
        ordering = ['new', 'deprecated']
```

I've tried using multiple `order_by` on the queryset as well but that doesn't do the trick either. Right now, I get a list with the new ones at the beginning, followed by the objects which are neither and the deprecated ones at the end. What I want is for the new ones to be at the top, immediately followed by the deprecated ones and then the rest which are neither. Is there a direct way to do what I want?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047107/order-a-django-queryset-with-specific-objects-first) doesn't work for me as the order should be based on fields rather than specific ids.

Comment: Can it be that a record is new and deprecated at the same time?

Comment: Nope, it's either or. But the queryset might contain both types at the same time.

Comment: I would have thought it would be `ordering = ["-new", "-deprecated"]`. What order do you get with that?