# Extracting data as a list from a Pandas dataframe while preserving order

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

Suppose I have some Pandas dataframe `df` that has a column called "HEIGHT", among many other columns.

If I issue `list(df["HEIGHT"])`, then this will give me a list of the items in that column in the exact order in which they were in the dataframe, i.e. ordered by the index of the dataframe.

Is that always the case? The `df["HEIGHT"]` command will return a Series and `list()` will convert it to a list. But are these operations always order-preserving? Interestingly in the [book[1](http://wesmckinney.com/pages/book.html) by the Pandas author (!), from my reading so far, it is unclear to me, when these elementary operations preserve order; is order perhaps always preserved, or is there some simple rule to know when order should be preserved?

Comment: have you tried `df['HEIGHT'].tolist()` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The order of elements in a pandas Series (i.e., a column in a pandas DataFrame) will not change unless you do something that makes it change. And the order of a python `list` is guaranteed to reflect insertion order ([SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694034/is-a-python-list-guaranteed-to-have-its-elements-stay-in-the-order-they-are-inse)).

So yes, `df[0].tolist()` (slightly faster than `list(df[0])`) should always yield a Python list of elements in the same order as the elements in `df[0]`.

Comment: Accepted your answer because of the nice info that `tolist` is faster. Why though - because it is not a Python built-in function, but a specialized function of the pandas DataFrame class?

Comment: @l7ll7 Yes, in general, when working with data structure libraries like pandas or numpy, you should use their interfaces rather than python equivalents for better performance.

Answer (score 3):

Order will always be preserved. When you use the `list` function, you provide it an iterator, and construct a list by iterating over it. For more information on iterators, you might want to read [PEP 234](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/) on iterators.

The iteration order is determined by the iterator you provide it. Iterators for a series are provided by `pd.Series.__iter__()` (the standard way to access an iterator for an object, which is searched for by the `list` method and similar). For more information on iteration and indexing in Pandas, consider reading the [relevant API reference section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/api.html#indexing-iteration) and the much more in-depth [indexing documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/indexing.html).

Comment: +1 For the super pristine explanation regarding iterators. I would accepted both answer, but since I couldn't I also courtesy-upvoted a few others of your answers ;)