# How do I store the same input in different places and have a different name for each answer going up by 1 each time? like, name1, name2, etc

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a game where the user will input the number of players, and then each player will enter their own name. I want to be able to store each of the player's names and be able to recall their name to notify them that it is their turn. I know I don't have much done so far, but I can't really get anywhere without solving this problem.

```
num_of_players = input("# of players: ")
num_of_players = int(num_of_players)

player = num_of_players

while player > 0:
    name = input("Player name: ")
    player -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your game will have some kind of scoring and potentially need to store other data about the player, you could create a Player class like so

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, score):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
```

Then, define a list to store your `Player` objects:

```py
players = []
```

Finally, you can iterate over the number of players the user enters and store the `Player` for each player.

```py
player_count = int(input("# of players: "))
for i in range(1, player_count + 1):
    name = input(f"Player {i}'s name: ")
    players.append(Player(name, 0))
```

You can then consume this data like so

```py
for p in players:
    print(f"{p.name} - {p.score}")
```

Example output:

```xml
# of players: 2
Player 1's name: Joshua
Player 2's name: Lucan
Joshua - 0
Lucan - 0
```

Comment: For the game, the players are going to roll dice (I already have that program completed) for their turn. How am I able to go through the names of them to say it is their turn and then they do the dice program and then it says the next players turn and the cycle repeats until a stop command?

Comment: You would have your main game loop and then an inner loop that iterates over each player, allowing them to have their turn. The player list will stay in the [same order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13694053/11916773).